# what kind of integral domain do the non-infinite surreals form?

Tags: ring-theory, surreal-numbers

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain
mentions the following chain of inclusions:

Principal Ideal domains $\subset$ Unique Factorization domains $\subset$ GCD domains $\subset$ Integrally Closed domains

Do the non-infinite surreals (i.e. those that are either infinitesimal or finite) form an I.C. domain? Do they form a GCD domain? A U.F. domain? A P.I. domain?

Comment: Do the non-infinite surreals even comprise a set? The wiki says the surreals are a proper class, and I have a superstitious feeling that keeping the infinitesimals, even after throwing out the infinite elements, might still be a proper class. If so, it technically isn't a ring at all.

Comment: The non-infinite surreals form a proper class. But the question is still interesting: we can allow proper-class-sized Rings. I hope others will comment.

Comment: As for the quality of unique factorization domain, it fails, since the units are finite surreals and there are no irreductible elements: every positive infiinitesimal $\varepsilon$ is the square of its square root.

Answer (score 0):

It's a local ring whose unique maximal ideal is the class of infinitesimal elements.

In fact, I believe for any two ideals, you have either $I \subseteq J$ or $J \subseteq I$. (thus, you have a GCD domain)

All of the non-infinitesimal elements are units, so the only nontrivial aspect of 'factorization' is *how* infinitesimal an element is. e.g. $\epsilon^2$ is more infinitesimal than $\epsilon$, as can be seen by observing $\frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon}$ is infinitesimal, or equivalently, that $\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2}$ is infinite.

The maximal ideal is certainly not principal; every ideal $(\epsilon)$ fails to contain the element $|\epsilon|^{1/2}$.

(these are true things for any real closed field with infinite elements, which I believe the surreals are, barring size issues)

I imagine the "degree" of infinitesimallitude is measured again by positive surreal numbers; e.g. given any two sets $L$ and $R$ of infinitesimals where everything in $L$ is less infinitesimal than everything in $R$, there should be infinitesimals strictly between $L$ and $R$. But I'm not experienced with this, so take my claim with a grain of salt.

Comment: I'm interested in this solution, but I know nearly nothing about the surreals. I looked at the wiki with the description above in mind, but all I got was a headache. You're saying it might be a valuation domain. Can you mention what construction makes that easy to see? Or whatever other breadcrumbs you used? Thanks

Comment: @rschwieb: It's the ordering; everything is either infinite, infinitesimal, or neither; the finite numbers form a ring and the inverse of an infinite number is infinitesimal. For most of the post, all I was using is the fact the surreals are an ordered, nonarchimedean field, and occasionally using that it's furthermore a real closed field. Only the last paragraph has anything to do with the surreals specficially.

Comment: I guess what makes me wary is the statement at the wiki that the surreals are actually a proper class and not a set. I start to wonder what can go wrong in that case. I guess a lot of the same logic that works for rings still goes through, set or not.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Thanks!  Why do any two non-zero elements have a GCD?

Comment: @Haidar: Because one of them divides the other one.